# Getting all the strings that start with "_" and end in 10 random characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, wildcard

I have this array:

```
Array = ["rubbish3","_B07TLNWCSV","_A674598385","_U8965H456NV","crapcrap","crapcrap23]
```

I want all the values that start with "_" and are followed by 10 random characters.

So the return in this instance would be

```
Array = ["_B07TLNWCSV","_A674598385","_U8965H456NV"]
```

How would I do this in Javascript?

## UPDATE

Say If I want to get all the elements on a webpage that follow the same rule,

On a webpage the element is like so:

```
<tr id="_B07TLNWCSV">data</tr>
```

how would I get all table row elements that follow the rule "_(10 RANDOM CHARS)"

I understand that **querySelectorAll** which get all the elements that follow the rule but I can't get it working.

Comment: Use `Array.filter()` with a function that tests whether the length is 11 and the first character is `_`.

Comment: Have you looked at `filter`, `indexOf`, and `length`?

Comment: Completely agree with @Barmar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()`, filtering words that start with `_` and have a `11` chars length ( `_` + 10 chars )

```js
const array = ["rubbish3","_B07TLNWCSV","_A674598385","_U8965H456NV","crapcrap","crapcrap23"];

const result = array.filter(word => word.startsWith('_') && word.length === 11);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Taki If I want to getelementsbyclassname("_(RANDOM CHARACTERS)") is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` method and a regular expression for this:

```js
var array = ["rubbish3","_B07TLNWCSV","_A674598385","_U8965H456NV","crapcrap","crapcrap23"];
var filteredArray = array.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.match(/^_.{10}$/);
});
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

`^_` => the string must start with a `_`.

`.{10}` => then we must have ten characters (`.` means any character)

`$` => end of string, i.e. the string must stop there, we can't have any more characters.

**Edit:** Regarding your question update, the simplest way to target these elements is to add a common class name to all of them, say:

```
<tr id="_B07TLNWCSV" class="data">data</tr>
<tr id="_B07TLNWDSA" class="data">data</tr>
<tr id="_B07TLNWCXB" class="data">data</tr>
```

And then use `getElementsByClassName("data")` to retrieve the elements.

Comment: If I want to getelementsbyclassname("_(RANDOM CHARACTERS)") is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that you might looking for. 
Hope my code would be useful!

```js
const array=["rubbish3","_B07TLNWCSV","_A674598385","_U8965H456NV","crapcrap","crapcrap23", "_123456789123"];
let newArray=[];
array.forEach(function(word){
  if(word.length==11&&word[0]=="_") newArray.push(word);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: If I want to getelementsbyclassname("_(RANDOM CHARACTERS)") is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but if you want my advice use `querySelector()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `filter()` along with hardcoded index `[0]` and string length `11`.

```js
const array = ["rubbish3","_B07TLNWCSV","_A674598385","_U8965H456NV","crapcrap","crapcrap23"];

const result = array.filter((f) => { return f[0] === '_' && f.length === 11 });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If I want to getelementsbyclassname("_(RANDOM CHARACTERS)") is this possible?